# Was the Maltese Falcon a real historical artifact?

Tags: middle-ages, malta

Am wondering if any of this is true (Hammett, [*The Maltese Falcon*](https://archive.org/details/maltesefalcon01hamm/), p. 150).

> "The
> archives of the Order from the twelfth century on are still at Malta.
> They are not intact, but what is there holds no less than three"—he
> held up three fingers—"referenees that can't be to anything else but
> this jeweled falcon. In J. Delaville Le Roulx's *[Les Archives de
> l'Ordre de Saint-Jean](https://archive.org/details/lesarchiveslabib00dela/)* there is a reference to it—oblique to be sure,
> but a reference still. And the unpublished—because unfinished at the
> time of his death—supplement to Paoli's *[Dell' origine ed instituto del
> sacro militar ordine](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_tLF3hT0rhVkC/)* has a clear and unmistakable statement of the
> facts I am telling you."
>
> "All right," Spade said.
>
> "All right, sir.
> Grand Master Villiers de l'Isle d'Adam had this foothigh jeweled bird
> made by Turkish slaves in the castle of St. Angelo and sent it to
> Charles, who was in Spain. He sent it in a galley commanded by a
> French knight named Cormier or Corvere, a member of the Order." His
> voice dropped to a whisper again. "It never reached Spain." He smiled
> with compressed lips and asked: "You know of Barbarossa, Redbeard,
> Khair-ed-Din? No? A famous admiral of buccaneers sailing out of
> Algiers then. Well, sir, he took the Knights' galley and he took the
> bird. The bird went to Algiers. That's a fact. That's a fact that the
> French historian Pierre Dan put in one of his letters from Algiers.

Googling just turns up page after page about movie props.

**Clarification**: this question asks specifically *the details about the falcon*, starting with bare existance.

**Addition**: a [book by Pierre Dan](https://archive.org/details/histoiredebarbar00danp/), unknown whether it contains the relevant letter.

**[More](http://www.januarymagazine.com/features/hammettlayman.html)**:

> It is not clear exactly how Hammett got his material. He is not known
> to have read French, medieval or otherwise, or Italian. His references
> must have been gleaned from a secondary source. I have been unable to
> locate a simple narrative of the rental agreement between the
> Hospitallers of St. John and Charles V of Spain that Hammett would
> have had available to him with all of the detail Gutman provides. I
> think there must be one; but what is clear, nonetheless, is that
> Hammett was reading widely, carefully and thoughtfully.

Comment: We don't signal edits, so I made a small clarification there. Other comment removed.

Comment: FWIW there isn't a shred of a mention of this story on [Philippe Villers de l'Isle-Adam's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Villiers_de_L%27Isle-Adam).

Comment: J. Delaville Le Roulx's _Les Archives de l'Ordre de Saint-Jean_ [certainly exists](https://archive.org/details/lesarchiveslabib00dela/page/n8), so if you brush up on your French you can probably check if the oblique reference exists ;-)

Comment: And  Paoli's _Dell' origine ed i[n]stituto del sacro militar ordine_ [also exists](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_tLF3hT0rhVkC/page/n4), but the unpublished supplement is probably harder to lay hands on - so your Italian can lay unpolished for now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the "Maltese Falcon" itself is fictional the object might have been inspired by a real one - albeit one without the exciting Knights Templar and Pirates(!) backstory. The "Kniphausen Hawk" is a bejeweled drinking vessel dating to at least 1697 and is currently owned by the Duke of Devonshire, being ~15 inches high and literally [*covered* in gemstones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kfBm.jpg) it would certainly fit the bill (pun intended!) but it has nothing to do with Malta or Algiers and I've not been able to find any evidence to show that Hammet was aware of the Kniphausen Hawk.

Comment: Actually, [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Maltese_Falcon_(1941_film)) says "The 'Maltese Falcon' itself is said to have been based on the 'Kniphausen Hawk'."

Comment: And it's the Hospitallers not the Templars.

Comment: @Tomas By - "is said" by whom?  The Wikipedia article references a 2010 Daily Mail piece in which we find "the Duke in his study... cradling the fabulous Kniphausen Hawk", immediately revealing what "is said" about it.  I'm happy to be contradicted, but I think I can be forgiven for suspecting that the only people this "is said" by are those with a commercial interest in such a thing being said...

Comment: @Jeremy that ties with what I've always read about it - none of the various articles I've seen making this claim ever seem to be able to cite a source for the claim which makes it anecdotal at best.

Comment: @Jeremy: I just noticed it when googling. But I don't think Hammett made the whole thing up, all by himself.

Comment: Read the pun - clicked +1! ...How do you drink from that thing though?

Comment: @TomasBy I can't find the source right now (it's been a few years and I can't seem to recreate the google path I took back then) but IIRC Lillian Hellmn (Hammett's lover) claimed exactly that (that Hammett had made the whole thing up) in a letter to Otto Penzler

Comment: Colour me unconvinced. He could have just heard of  this Kniphausen Hawk somewhere and she knew nothing about it.

Comment: @TomasBy Agreed, it's hardly convincing evidence one way or the other. Personally I think the Kniphausen Hawk is the most likely inspiration but unless there's some concrete evidence of a link somewhere it remains just a likely theory.

Comment: Notably though, the falcon seen in the film looks nothing like the Kniphausen Hawk.  It's not jewel-encrusted, it's not in that dramatic attacking pose, it's just black and sitting there.  I suppose the book did mention "jeweled", even if the film didn't.  But neither the book nor the movie have it as a drinking vessel.

Comment: Actually: "a glorious golden falcon encrusted from head to foot
with the finest jewels in their coffers." (p. 149) "It had been [...] painted or enameled over to look like nothing more than a fairly interesting black statuette." (p. 151)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yeah the Kniphausen Hawk is technically a drinking vessel although if you didn't know you would be hard pressed to tell just by looking at it as the actual vessel is pretty well concealed. And given we are dealing with a work of fiction here - if the Maltese Falcon *is* inspired by the Hawk changing it from drinking vessel to just a plain statuette would be a minor tweak compared to giving it a completely different name and back story!

Answer (score 13):

> These are facts, historical facts, not schoolbook history, not Mr. Wells's history, but history nevertheless. ...

I believe what this is saying is that the following information isn't written down in any history book anywhere, but (in Hammet's fictional universe) did actually happen.

Its meant to both lay out some background information to the reader, and to clue them in that *this is stuff the author made up* to make his story interesting, and help drive its plot.

As far as real world information goes, you should translate the quoted sentence above as "These are fictional facts my author made up, that are only valid within the confines of this book."

Comment: Yeah, it's not facts, that stuff is made out of dreams.